# Flutter/Firebase location tracking and getting nearest user

Tags: flutter, firebase, geolocation

I want to track the location of the user of my Flutter App and save it to FirebaseFirestore. Then I want to show all the users that are e.g. 10 meters away from the user.
How can I make this as efficient as possible?
When I only loop over the user documents in Firestore and then calculate all the distances, the App gets really slow when I have too many users.

The location doesn't need to be precise, so I thought about only saving an area of 10x10 meters and then just using the where() function because if you are close to each other you can use isEqual. Is this the best way? If so, how can I achieve this as efficiently as possible?

Thanks for the help